Simplify expression with ternary operator
Can the following code be shortened/simplified without introducing a division?
a, b, c and y are arbitrary integer values:
int x = 0;
if (y > 0) {
    x = c < y * a ? 1 : c < y * b ? 2 : 4;
}
if (y < 0) {
    x = c > y * a ? 1 : c > y * b ? 2 : 4;
}


Can you describe what you are trying to do rather than have us figure it out?  Your values of y,a,b, and c have no context.

I would use a method. Not necessarily simpler but more efficient.

first check to see if y == 0.
then check if y < 0 and return the value.
else return the remaining result.

public static int evaluate(int a, int b, int c, int y) {
    if (y == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (y > 0) {
        return c < y * a ? 1 : c < y * b ? 2 : 4;
    } 
    return  c > y * a ? 1 : c > y * b ? 2 : 4;
}

Updated
Simple timing tests such as this are not usually reliable to check one implementation against another.  But this should reasonably show that:

your other method also seems to work
that after 10 million iterations of not only comparing the two results but generating random numbers to do the test, simplifications will probably not improve much in terms of computing time.


Random r = new Random();
long start = System.nanoTime();
for (int i = 0; i < 10_000_000; i++) {
    int y = r.nextInt(-1000, 1000);
    int a = r.nextInt(-1000, 1000);
    int b = r.nextInt(-1000, 1000);
    int c = r.nextInt(-1000, 1000);
    int x = 0;
    int y1 = y;
    int c1 = c;
    if (y < 0) {
        y = -y;
        c = -c;
    }
    if (y != 0) {
        x = c < y * a ? 1 : c < y * b ? 2 : 4;
    }

    int x1 = evaluate(a, b, c1, y1);
    if (x != x1) {
        System.out.printf("Oops! a = %d, b = %d, c1 = %d, y1 = %d%n", a, b, c1, y1);
    }
}

prints something like the following on my Windows i7
0.635331 (or 635 ms)


thanks. This part of code is part of an algorithm which would be too complex to describe here. What I tried to achive is to unite the both lines where x is computed. I rewrote this according to my (upcoming) answer.

You may find my updated answer useful.

That's great, thank you. I derived the simplified code snipped from a sketch and actually tested the result in a similar way as you did. Performance should be more or less equal with this simplification, yes. But IMO there is less redundancy in code for computing x. And I learned something new, 10_000_000 is a readable and valid expression in java :)

@user27772  Yeah.  For parsing reasons using commas wouldn't work (or be easy to implement).  So you can place underscores just about anywhere and in any length in a numerical constant.  You can find that and related information in the Java Language Specification under the section on literals.

IMO the original code snipped can be re-written as:
    int x = 0;
    if (y < 0) {
        y = -y;
        c = -c;
    }
    if (y != 0) {
        x = c < y * a ? 1 : c < y * b ? 2 : 4;
    }

IMO this would be a nice answer from a KI-based system ;-)
